# MySQL resultset should contain rows with common value in columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows:

```
id, section, row, seat
1  Stalls    A     25
2  Stalls    A     26
3  Stalls    B     1
4  Stalls    B     2
5  Stalls    B     3
6  Stalls    B     4
7  Lounge    C     1
8  Lounge    C     2
```

As you can probably guess, the table represents a seating plan. I need to be able to query the table to  give me adjacent seats. For eg, if I want three seats, it should give me seat id's 3,4,5 and not 1,2,3. However, if I want two seats, it should give me seat id's 1,2

In sql terms, I need to be able to query for rows that have the same values in 'section' and 'row' columns. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, section, row,seat,rank
from (select id, section, row,seat, 
      @rank:=if(@lastsection=section and @lastrow=row and @lastseat=seat-1,@rank,@rank+1) rank,
      @lastsection:=section,@lastrow:=row,@lastseat:=seat
      from tblA, (select @lastsection:='',@lastrow:='',@lastseat:='', @rank:=1)v
      order by section,row,seat)s
GROUP BY rank
HAVING count(rank)>=numberofseatdesired;
```

This would return the id,section, row,starting seat that have the adjacent seat number you want. You might need second query to retrieve detailed id for each and every of the seat.

Comment: Thank you. Apologies for not having documented the effort I put in trying to get it working. It was clearly off the mark. :)